# "From the study of... something" vs "By studying something"

Tags: meaning, sentence-construction, grammaticality

Say I'm stating a conclusion based on previous studies I might have done. Consider the sentence

> 1. From the study of "something" we can conclude that...

vs

> 2. By studying "something" we can conclude that

Are they equivalent? Are there any differences? Are they both grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1):

Both are grammatically correct.

It's a subtle point, but referring to "the study of Something" makes it sound like you are referring to the entire field of research. Saying "By studying Something" makes it more clear that you mean the specific studies you have conducted.

You might make this even more clear by saying "Based on the studies **Title X**, **Title Y**, **Title Z**, we can conclude..."

Comment: I was thinking more as something that is result of an analysis.